# Iterate each digit in an integer and do mod 11

Tags: java

I am trying to do some program and need of some help. For example,  I entered this number on a textbox: 00669253, then for each number i want to multiply it with the number 87654321 so for example

(0x8) + (0x7) + (6x6).... and so on and then get the sum of all the number and do a mod of 11. How can I do this?

Thanks for your advance help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first convert the number into `String` and then you can do it like this :

```
String no1="00669253";
String no2="87654321";
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<no1.length();i++){
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(""+no1.charAt(i))*Integer.parseInt(""+no2.charAt(i));
}
```

After that you can do any operation on `sum`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "112211";
        String s2 = "010101";
        char[] sDummy = s.toCharArray();
        char[] s2Dummy = s2.toCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sDummy.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("multiplying..." + sDummy[i] + "with " + s2Dummy[i] + "and adding prev sum " + sum + " to it");
            sum = sum + (Integer.parseInt(sDummy[i] + "") * Integer.parseInt(s2Dummy[i] + ""));
        }
        sum = sum % 11;
        System.out.println("sum with mod is = " + sum);
    }
}
```

You need to add some checks in case if length of both string differs

Comment: That will add not produce the correct result, as you multiply the character codes and not the actual integer value represented by the character.

Comment: Yes you are right, i just figured it out, need to convert it to int before multiplying. Editing the correct version

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
public class TestMult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "00669253";
        String second = "87654321";

        long sum = 0L;
        if (first.length() == second.length()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
                int firstInt = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(i));
                int secondInt = Character.getNumericValue(second.charAt(i));
                sum += firstInt * secondInt;
            }
            System.out.println("result: " + sum % 11);
        } else {
            System.err.println("lengths are not equal.");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
    String inputValue = "00669253";
    String multipleValue="87654321";

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputValue.length(); i++)
            {
                result += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(inputValue.charAt(i))) * 
                Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(multipleValue.charAt(i)));
            }
```